# array_count_values of a multi dimensional array?

Tags: php

I have searched this question a lot. But I could not find a proper solution anywhere. Just like you do an `array_count_values()` for a single dimensional array, what do you do for a multi dimensional array if you want similar type of a solution?

For example-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [07/11] => 134
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [07/11] => 134
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [07/11] => 145
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [07/11] => 145
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [07/12] => 134
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [07/12] => 99
        )
)
```

The output that I want is-

```
Date: 07/11, ID: 134, Count: 2
Date: 07/11, ID: 145, Count: 2
Date: 07/12, ID: 135, Count: 1
Date: 07/12, ID: 99, Count: 1
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You could either run a nested foreach loop or create a recursive function to navigate multi-dimensions

Comment: I figured out I need to use a nested loop to navigate multi-dimensions but I am not able to figure out how will I count unique IDs for each date.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using the variable `$arr` for your array, you could do this:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2){
        $index = $key2.'-'.$value2;
        if (array_key_exists($index, $out)){
            $out[$index]++;
        } else {
            $out[$index] = 1;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($out);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [07/11-134] => 2
    [07/11-145] => 2
    [07/12-134] => 1
    [07/12-99] => 1
)
```

Here's another version that produces it as a multidimensional array:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2){
        if (array_key_exists($key2, $out) && array_key_exists($value2, $out[$key2])){
            $out[$key2][$value2]++;
        } else {
            $out[$key2][$value2] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [07/11] => Array
        (
            [134] => 2
            [145] => 2
        )

    [07/12] => Array
        (
            [134] => 1
            [99] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: The second solution was amazing. I never thought this could be done this way. Thanks, so much I learned :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
  $array = array(array('07/11' => '134'), array('07/11' => '134'), array('07/12' => '145'));
  $count = array();
  foreach ($array as $val) {
    foreach ($val as $key => $subval) {
      $count[$key]++;
    }
  }
  print_r($count);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But your solution will just give me count of unique IDs. I want it date wise.

Comment: Oops... See last revision (sorry about that). :)

Comment: beautiful solution. +1

Comment: Your new solution gives me the count of unique date only. Not the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

In your place I would have altered the structure of the data array. In your case:

```
Array( 
    [07/11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 134,
            [1] => 134,
            [2] => 145,
            [3] => 145,
            ...
        )
)
```

Comment: Interesting. How do I proceed after doing this?

Comment: Also, this is not always a viable solution as many times one will need to work with an already fixed data..

Answer (score 0):

Smart way, We know that [`array_count_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php): Counts all the values of an array

> Just like you do an array_count_values() for a single dimensional array, what do you do for a multi dimensional array.

We do it by turning it to one single dimensional array, then we call our funciton

```php
$input = array(
    array('07/11' => '134'),
    array('07/11' => '134'), 
    array('07/11' => '145'),
    array('07/11' => '145'),
    array('07/12' => '134'), 
    array('07/12' => '99')
    );
$output = [];
foreach ($input as $inner){
    foreach ($inner as $key => $value){
        $output[] = "Date: $key, ID: $value, Count:";
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT*: as you expect*

```php
foreach(array_count_values($output) as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key $value<br>";
}

/*Date: 07/11, ID: 134, Count: 2
Date: 07/11, ID: 145, Count: 2
Date: 07/12, ID: 135, Count: 1
Date: 07/12, ID: 99, Count: 1*/
```

Updated for cases where there are multiple elements in each sub-array

```
   $input = array(
    array('07/11' => '134', '07/12' => '100'),
    array('07/11' => '134', '07/12' => '100'), 
    array('07/11' => '145', '07/12' => '200'),
    array('07/11' => '145', '07/12' => '200'),
    array('07/12' => '134', '07/13' => '300'), 
    array('07/12' => '99', '07/13' => '400')
    );
$output = [];
foreach ($input as $inner){
    if (count($inner) > 1) {
        // handle multiple elements in sub-array
        foreach ($inner as $key => $value){
            if (isset($output[$key][$value])) {
                $output[$key][$value]++;
            } else {
                $output[$key][$value] = 1;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // handle single element in sub-array
        foreach ($inner as $key => $value){
            $output[] = "Date: $key, ID: $value, Count:";
        }
    }
}

if (count($output) > 1) {
    // handle multiple elements in output array
    foreach ($output as $date => $counts) {
        foreach ($counts as $id => $count) {
            echo "Date: $date, ID: $id, Count: $count<br>";
        }
    }
} else {
    // handle single element in output array
    foreach(array_count_values($output) as $key => $value) {
        echo "$key $value<br>";
    }
}
```

**Result would be:**

```
Date: 07/11, ID: 134, Count: 2
Date: 07/11, ID: 145, Count: 2
Date: 07/12, ID: 100, Count: 2
Date: 07/12, ID: 134, Count: 1
Date: 07/12, ID: 99, Count: 1
Date: 07/13, ID: 300, Count: 1
Date: 07/13, ID: 400, Count: 1
```

Comment: this will not work if there are multiple elements in each sub array

Comment: check it now, for cases where if there are multiple elements in each sub-array!

Comment: looks wrong. I think it will not count unique rows in multidimensional array.