# How to make Chart grapht php?

Tags: php

I want to count the result of the database according to an index of data and set it again.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM hit WHERE date BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE() ";
    $sor=$this->vt()->query($sql);
    $array=array();
    $cek=$sor->FetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

database 
id
date
type
ip
category
page
ref
reflink
results

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [category] => 0
            [page] => 0
            [ip] => ::1
            [tip] => t
            [date] => 2016-10-24 
            [ref] => 
            [reflink] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [category] => 0
            [page] => 0
            [ip] => ::1
            [type] => t
            [date] => 2016-10-24 
            [ref] => 
            [reflink] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [category] => 0
            [page] => 0
            [ip] => ::1
            [type] => t
            [date] => 2016-10-24
            [ref] => 
            [reflink] => 
        )



    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26
            [category] => 0
            [page] => 0
            [ip] => 127.0.0.1
            [type] => t
            [date] => 2016-10-28
            [ref] => 
            [reflink] => 
        )

)
```

I make date count.I want to show these values as graphics
24.10 : 3
28.10 : 1
How do these values day by day counted?
[for Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eCmA.png)

Comment: use `array_count_values()` functions

Comment: Samir example code ?How do  values day by day counted?Thank you

Comment: see this solution [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642469/array-count-values-of-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here its is

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $date[] = $value['date'];
}
print_r (array_count_values($date));
```

Comment: thanks a lot working <br>
' foreach ($hcek as $value) {
$date[] = $value['date'];
}
        $hitget=array_count_values($date);
$hitkeyim= implode(",",array_keys($hitget));
$hitkey=explode(",",$hitkeyim);
$hitsay=COUNT($hitkey);
$hitvalim= implode(",",$hitget);
$hitval=explode(",",$hitvalim); '