# PHP: Count and sum associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array which contains 10k records or so

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 111
            [1] => 14/02/2020
            [2] => 36
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 222
            [1] => 29/12/2019
            [2] => 1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 222
            [1] => 27/11/2019
            [2] => 3
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 333
            [1] => 12/09/2019
            [2] => 4
        )
```

The result I want would be to count how many times each value at `[0]` occurs along with the sum of what's in `[2]` to show something like the following

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 111
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 36
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 222
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 333
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 4
        )
```

I have tried a few things but the code got too unwieldy so I have now come back to a blank piece of paper. I tried [array_count_values of a multi dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642469/array-count-values-of-a-multi-dimensional-array) which is close as it gives me the count of what is at `[0]` but seems a bit overkill and I don't get the sum of `[2]`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$entries = [
    [111, '14/02/2020', 36],
    [222, '29/12/2019', 1],
    [222, '27/11/2019', 3],
    [333, '12/09/2019', 4],
];

$results = [];
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $results[$entry[0]] = [
        $entry[0],
        ($results[$entry[0]][1] ?? 0) + 1,
        ($results[$entry[0]][2] ?? 0) + $entry[2],
    ];
}
$results = array_values($results);

print_r($results);
```

or

```
<?php

$entries = [
    [111, '14/02/2020', 36],
    [222, '29/12/2019', 1],
    [222, '27/11/2019', 3],
    [333, '12/09/2019', 4],
];

$results = [];
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    if (!isset($results[$entry[0]])) {
        $results[$entry[0]] = [$entry[0], 0, 0];
    }
    ++$results[$entry[0]][1];
    $results[$entry[0]][2] += $entry[2];
}
$results = array_values($results);

print_r($results);
```